# Display characters entered recently with out variable in assembly?

Tags: assembly

Hello i want to know how to show a character with out variable 'char' like this

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg1 db 'Hay go 1 phim: $'
msg2 db 13,10,'Ky tu nhan duoc la: $'
char db '$'
.code
main proc 
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax 

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,msg1
    int 21h

    mov ah,01h    
    int 21h
    mov char,al    

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,msg2
    int 21h

    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,char
    int 21h

    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
endp
end main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must store `al` after read char somewhere, as the `dl` is used for low 8b of `msg2` address, and value in `al` is modified by the `msg2` output. So simple `mov dl,al` alone will not work.

There are different ways, how to preserve some value for x86 CPU. Your `mov [char],al` is just one option (a nicely readable and easy to understand, so a good fit for most of the situations).

Other option is to keep it in some register, which is not modified by the code between read and write. From the quick look it looks like only `ax` and `dx` is modified between, so you can store that char for example into `cl`.

Example:

```
...
mov ah,01h    
int 21h
mov cl,al

... output msg2

mov ah,02h
mov dl,cl
int 21h
```

Other option is to store the value into the stack temporarily:

```
...
mov ah,01h    
int 21h
push ax  ; store al

... output msg2

mov ah,02h
pop dx   ; restore al directly into dl
int 21h
```

Comment: Thank for your help :D